# convert a string number starts with `00` to `+` in java

Tags: java

I want to convert a string number starts with `00` to `+` such as `0046760963101` to `+46760963101`. Is there any solution to handle it via regex?

If not what solution do you recommend?

Addenda :

If it starts with `000` or more, I do not want to replace with + sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inculding the added requirement: If it starts with 000 or more, I do not want to replace with + sign.

```
String normalized = phone;
if ( !phone.matches("000+([0-9]+)") && phone.startsWith("00")) {
    normalized = "+"+phone.substring(2);
}
```

Check you input in regex tester like: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If s starts with 000, I don't want to get + sign

Comment: You should have included this in your question.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. do you know the solution ?

Answer (score 7):

with regex assuming the input is a numeric string

```
s.replaceFirst("^00", "+")
```

or with regex if you aren't sure of the input format

```
s.replaceFirst("^00([0-9]+)$", "+$1")
```

or with a simple match

```
s.startsWith("00") ? "+"+s.substring(2) : s
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If s starts with 000, I don't want to get + sign.

Comment: s.replaceFirst("^00([^0][0-9]+)$", "+$1")

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number="0046760963101";

    if(number.startsWith("00")) {
        number=number.replaceFirst("00", "+");
    }

    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the 00 with a + like so:

```
String str = "0046760963101";
    String newStr = "+";
    for (int i = 2; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        newStr += str.charAt(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
String str = "0046760963101";
String replaced = str.charAt(2) == '0' ? str :  str.substring(0, 2).replace("00", "+") + str.substring(2);
System.out.println(replaced);
```

will print:

```
+46760963101
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If s starts with 000, I don't want to get + sign